# how to insert two table related, in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to insert my information to `information table` and then insert `information_id` to `advertise table` , in one step

I get the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`baroot_laravel`.`advertise`, CONSTRAINT `advertise_information_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`information_id`) REFERENCES `information` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `advertise` (`jobs_sub_category_id`, `area_id`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 2015-10-18 07:04:13, 2015-10-18 07:04:13))
```

Here is my codes :

**Advertise_Model :**

```
class Advertise_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'advertise';
    protected $fillable = ['jensiat','information_id','wage_range_id','jobs_sub_category_id','jobs_type_id','age_range_id','experience_id','confirmed','description','city_id','area_id','academic_degree_id'];

    public function Information()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Information_Model','information_id','id');
    }

}
```

**Information_Model :**

```
class Information_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'information';
    protected $fillable = ['person_name','company_name','company_phone','person_mobile','location_id','person_id','email','website'];
}
```

**And my save to db controller :**

```
public function AdminStore(Request $request)
    {
        Advertise_Model::create($request->all())->with(Information_Model::create($request)->all());
        //Information_Model::create($request->all());
        //Advertise_Model::create($request->all());
        return view('Administrator.Advertise.index');
    }
```

***EDITED :***

**Advertise Migration :**

```
Schema::create('advertise', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->charset = 'utf8';
            $table->collate = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->tinyInteger('jensiat');
            $table->integer('information_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('wage_range_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('jobs_sub_category_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('jobs_type_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->double('details_views')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('age_range_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('experience_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->tinyInteger('confirmed');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('admin_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('city_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('area_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->double('view');
            $table->integer('academic_degree_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('advertise', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('information_id')->references('id')->on('information');
        });
```

**Information Migration :**

```
Schema::create('information', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->charset = 'utf8';
            $table->collate = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('person_name');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('company_phone');
            $table->string('person_mobile');
            $table->integer('location_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->integer('person_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('website');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Please add your migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```
// Insert Information
$InformationCreate = new Information_Model;
$InformationCreate->person_name = $Request->person_name;
$InformationCreate->company_name = $Request->company_name;
$InformationCreate->company_phone = $Request->company_phone;
$InformationCreate->person_mobile = $Request->person_mobile ;
$InformationCreate->location_id = $Request->location_id;
$InformationCreate->person_id = $Request->person_id;
$InformationCreate->email = $Request->person_id;
$InformationCreate->website = $Request->email;
$InformationCreate->save();
```

After you have saved the Information you can use $InformationCreate->id to get the ID used during the creation of that Information record.

```
// Create Advertise
$AdvertiseCreate = new Advertise_Model;
$AdvertiseCreate->jensiat = $Request->jensiat;
$AdvertiseCreate->information_id = $InformationCreate->id;
```

Ofcourse there is maybe an beter way of doing this but it should work for you.